# Background cut off with html and body 100% height

Tags: html, css, height, document-body

I can't get html and body to have 100% height for some reason and I'm pulling my hair out trying to find out why. I'm using the following code and have scoured the web and Stackoverflow for answers, but nothing seems to be working:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  line-height:normal;
}
```

Here's a live demo:

http://dev1.onesizeup.com/

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you want the image fixed and covering your whole window, also such that text scrolls over it?

Comment: I wasn't intending to, but I like the suggestion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `height: 100%` on `html` forces its height to be that of the viewport (causing that cutoff).  Try setting `html`'s height to `auto` or removing `html` from the `html, body` rule.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Both Paulie_D and your answers work great. You saved me from going bald young.

Comment: Actually, I might have spoken a little too soon! I've removed the lorem ipsum text now, but the body isn't 100% now for some reason...

Comment: @Osu Ah! I see.  Try changing your body style (the one with the background image) to `html` and adding `background: none` to `body` or removing it entirely.  That may correct the issue, but it's hard to say.  Getting the background to work with sites that don't fill the page with content can be tricky.

Comment: @Osu Also you could try is adding overflow:auto; if you are using height:100%;. Ya for html tag.

Comment: Switching to the html tag worked perfectly. Updated the site so you can see (although it's a dev site, so will disappear soon!)

Answer (score 3):

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%; /* or min-height */
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: red;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jmp4m2xg/)